# How would changing the stress position in descriptive phrases change the meaning?

Tags: phonetics, stress, intonation

Usually in a phrase composed of an adjective followed by a noun, the noun gets the most stress, and in a phrasal verb like (go on, sit down, stand up) the preposition gets the most stress. However today I was reading in a book about American accent that for the sake of sentence balance, the stress can shift to the first element without changing the meaning. **The stress change indicates that it's not the end of the sentence, but rather, there is more to come.**

Example of the first scenario from a story (words in **bold** are stressed):

> There is a little **girl**. Her name is Goldilocks. She is in a sunny **forest**. She sees a small **house**.
>   She knocks on the door, but no one answers. She goes **inside**. In the large **room**, there are three **chairs**. Goldilocks sits on the biggest chair, but it is too **high**.

Example after paraphrasing of the same story:

> There is a **little** girl called Goldilocks. She is **walking** through a sunny forest and sees a small
>   house. She knocks on the door, but no one answers. She **goes** inside to see what's there. There are **three** chairs in the large room. Goldilocks sits on the biggest chair. It's too high for her to sit on.

To what extent is this accurate? Is it real when I shift the stress to the adjective in the second scenario, the meaning don't change as my book says?

And I quote from the book

> "One of the most fascinating things about spoken English is how the intonation prepares the listener for what is coming. As you know, the main job of intonation is to announce new information. However, there is a secondary function, and that is to alert the listener of changes down the road. Certain shifts will be dictated for the sake of **sentence balance**. Set phrases and contrast don't change, but the intonation of a **descriptive phrase** will move from the second word to the first, **without changing the meaning.** The stress change indicates that it's not the end of the sentence, but rather, there is more to come. This is why it is particularly important to speak in phrases, instead of word by word."

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You’ve asked a good question but you’ve changed more than one variable between examples: stresses (in bold) and word order. Are you asking only about stresses? Or also word order?

Comment: No, my question is only about the stress and whether the meaning really doesn't change. The change in word order in the second scenario is only to make the sentences longer. These both texts were copied and pasted here from my book that used them as examples to clarify the point.

Comment: Is there anything that makes you think it would? Or any other reason to doubt your book? Stresses can sometimes be lost between the spoken and written word, and with them sometimes subtle meaning. But the examples shown lack subtle meaning.

Comment: I understand according to my book for example shifting the stress to *little, three* in the second scenario doesn't necessarily give these adjectives extra emphasis or importance but only it's for the sake of sentence balance and to indicate there is more to come.. This is about American accent in case there is a distinction here from other accents.

Comment: I think you might mean speech "cadence".

Comment: Actually this word wasn't mentioned in my book. I reported the explanation almost literally. When I have doubts about something, I would really like asking native speakers for confirmation because this is will change the way I speak for good :)

Comment: @Jason Bassford Let me put it in another way. Forget about my first text. Do you agree that when stressing *little, three* in my second scenario doesn't give extra emphasis to these adjectives?

Comment: Anyway, the paraphrasing to make sentences longer is part of the question, because the idea here that we can change the stress position without difference in meaning when there is more to come and it is not the end of the sentence.

Comment: Yes I agree. We stress words to emphasize them, but my book claims that when words in bold are stressed in the second text, they are not given extra emphasis.. and that is I don't believe, so I am asking you here.

Comment: Ok, I'll quote what the book literally says because I don't have the link. Both example texts are copied and pasted literally from the book.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I edited my question and reported the explanation literally. Both texts are from the book to show the difference.

Comment: I believe the book you're discussing is [*American Accent Changes*](https://www.amazon.ca/American-Accent-Training-Downloadable-Audio/dp/1438010354/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1537822945&sr=8-1&keywords=american+accent+training) by Ann Cooke. I also found a site that shows the [section of text](https://www.passeidireto.com/arquivo/23249716/american-accent-training/35) in question, although without the bold text. This is text that accompanies an audio book. The bold words are not semantic but descriptive.

Comment: Also, you missed this: "When we practiced Goldilocks and the Three Bears the first time, on page 34, we had very short sentences so we didn't need sentence balance. All of the underlined descriptive phrases would otherwise be stressed on the second word, if the shift weren't needed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the rather opaque paragraph you cited concerns a terminal versus non-terminal [*intonation contour*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-intonation-contour-1691079), the latter signalling the end of a declarative sentence and the former a cue that something more is to follow. What is confusing about the paragraph is that whether a phrase is descriptive or not is irrelevant and, as you seem to have understood it, that the intonation phrase involved in this pattern does not suddenly stress syllables and words in some odd fashion contrary to how it otherwise would be spoken.

For instance, in the sentence

> He wanted to vacation in the Bahamas.

the word *Bahamas* has a falling intonation contour, i.e. a slight drop in pitch, focussing on the lexically stressed second syllable -*ha*- falling to *-mas*.

In contrast,

> He wanted to vacation in the Bahamas, but decided to go to the Yucatan instead.

Here the terminal intonation contour focusses on the syllable -*stead*. The syllable *-ha-* in *Bahamas*, however is spoken with a slightly higher pitch, falling slightly to *-mas*, i.e., a nonterminal intonation contour.

In a question,

> He wanted to vacation in the Bahamas?

at least the last syllable of *Bahamas* has to have a rising contour, spoken at a higher pitch.

You might stress “**little** girl” rather than “little **girl**” in the following contexts:

> She wasn’t a **little** girl, but rather tall for her age. (stress preparing for the contrasting statement).
>
> That **Little** girl keeps calling. (*Little* is understood as a surname.)

Thus if you say “a **(L)ittle** girl called Goldilocks,” then people might think you’re talking about a girl named Goldilocks Little.

So, no, changing stress about does change the meaning, or completely obscures it.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The author wasn't talking about intonation contour since it's a totally different chapter in the book. I had doubts because I read much about intonation from many sources but this idea introduced here was new to me and no one has ever mentioned it. I understand that if you read the second text, you would not stress the adjectives in bold if you don't wanna give them extra emphasis and thus meaning, but will you still not stress the first part of the phrasal verbs *walking, goes* if you read this story naturally and neutrally and you don't wanna give them extra emphasis?

Comment: _Walking_ has no more stress than it would naturally warrant; _-side_ of _inside_ has more stress than _goes_.